# Cygwin + git permission problems when trying to create a commit message

Tags: git, permissions, cygwin, vim

When I try to commit the first revision to my git repository (git commit) from Cygwin, I'm getting an error in gvim which says "Unable to open swap file for "foo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG" [New Directory]. I think it might be some sort of permission problem, but I've tried removing the read-only flag from the folder, as well as recursively adjusting the owner (using the windows property tab, not chown under Cygwin) to be the account I'm running under, without any luck. If I change the default editor to notepad, I get "The system cannot find the file specified", even though the file (COMMIT_EDITMSG) does exist and even contains:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes.
# (Comment lines starting with '#' will not be included)
# etc...
```

How can I troubleshoot this problem further?

Answer (score 3):

> Unable to open swap file for "foo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG" [New Directory].

Looks like the `git commit` is passing the file path as a Windows path, not a POSIX path. note the `\` in the message.

`gvim` is going to try to open `foo.gitCOMMIT_EDITMSG", which doesn't exist.

I don't use `git`, but I imagine it uses an environment var similar to `SVN_EDITOR`.  You may need to wrap the editing session with a small script that uses `cygpath` to change the file path from Windows to Posix separators.

```
#!/bin/bash
gvim "$(cygpath --unix "${1}")"
```

Caveat Emptor, untested.

Comment: Trying Ken G's script does not help me. I can see the value in a script like this, however simply manually typing gvim /cygdrive/d/Projects/foo/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG yields the same result from gvim. One other peculiarity I have now noticed is that gvim's titlebar says COMMIT_EDITMSG (d:\cygdrive\d\Projects\foo\.git) which is clearly an invalid path (there's no actual "cygdrive" folder on my D drive. I get a similar result when using the vim program built into cygwin, so I don't think its a gvim problem, but rather some issue with cygwin itself.

Comment: cygdrive is a cygwin artifact to allow for the access of "letter" drives without having to mount them.

I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: After reading through the options for "cygpath", I changed your script to say gvim "$(cygpath --windows "${1}")", which seems better but still not 100%, because I now get: "Unable to open swap file for "D:\Projects\foo\.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG^M" [New File]". Why is the "^M" appearing on the end?

Comment: On the '^M', I'd guess that the file was edited with Windows line endings (cr/lf) instead of unix line endings (lf)

Are you using the cygwin distribution of gvim or an independently installed version?

Comment: Are you using the git commit '-template=<file>' option or the `commit.template` configuration variable?

Comment: I'm using an independently installed version of gvim. My commit command is "git commit", so I assume it's using commit.template. Also, I did not create COMMIT_EDITMSG manually - I think it was created when I called "git add ."

Comment: My bridging script does not have any line ending on that line - it's only a 2 line script and that's the last line in the file. I went back and checked the line ending on the first line using cygwin's vim - still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You are using mingw or msysgit git in cygwin (*windows native*). This will not work when using a cygwin editor (gvim). The \ is no path seperator in POSIX, it rather escapes the next character.

You need to install the cygwin git package or use a proper mingw/msysgit editor.

It might also be that the mingw git.exe is in the PATH before /usr/bin. Fix your PATH then.

Such questions are usually handled via http://cygwin.com/problems.html, esp. cygcheck -s -v -r > cygcheck.out in the mailinglist. Then we could see more.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue first time but I found out that this is normal. Only I don't remember how to deal with Vim. I found solution in that link: http://vim.runpaint.org/basics/quitting-vim/. I used the vim command :x that resulted in saving my comment & committing modifcation.
You may read about this integration between Git & Vim through this link: http://vim.runpaint.org/extending/integrating-vim-with-git/.

Answer (score 0):

For `cygpath', try:

`cygdrive -a -m COMMIT_EDITMSG`

You possibly want path in the following style:

`D:/path/to/your/working_directory/.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG`